# How to implement Peano Arithmetic using Z3 Theorem prover?

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I study [Z3 Theorem prover](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html) and want to implement [Peano Arithmetic](http://logicprogramming.stanford.edu/examples/peano.html). I did it in Prolog and now I want to make using Satisfiability Modulo Theories Solver.

The following code is my implementation of the addition. I do not understand why it runs in a very long search for a model and then produces: `Z3Exception: model is not available.`

Can you please suggest how to implement Peano Arithmetic (add, mul, less)?

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

Nat = Datatype('Nat')
Nat.declare('Z')
Nat.declare('S', ('pred', Nat))
Nat = Nat.create()

Z = Nat.Z
S = Nat.S

P = Function('P', Nat, Nat, Nat, BoolSort())
x, y, z = Consts('x y z', Nat)

s.add(P(Z,Z,Z))
s.add(ForAll([x], P(Z, x, x)))   
s.add(ForAll([x], P(x, Z, x))) 
s.add(ForAll([x,y,z], Implies(P(S(x), y, S(z)), P(x, y, z)))) 

x1 = Const('x1', Nat)
s.add(P(S(Z), S(Z), x1))

if s.check():
  print(s.model())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "efficient" SMTLib way of doing this is to add recursive definitions for the functions. While what you wrote codes the intent correctly, it doesn't work well with the way SMT-solvers deal with recursive definitions. Instead, do the following:

```py
from z3 import *

Nat = Datatype('Nat')
Nat.declare('Z')
Nat.declare('S', ('pred', Nat))
Nat = Nat.create()
pred = Nat.pred
Z    = Nat.Z
S    = Nat.S

P       = RecFunction('P', Nat, Nat, Nat)
addArg1 = FreshConst(Nat)
addArg2 = FreshConst(Nat)

RecAddDefinition( P
                , [addArg1, addArg2]
                , If(addArg1 == Z, addArg2, S(P(pred(addArg1), addArg2)))
                )
```

Now, `P` is the addition over naturals. We can use it like this:

```py
x1 = Const('x1', Nat)

s = Solver()
s.add(x1 == P(S(Z), S(Z)))

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```py
sat
[x1 = S(S(Z))]
```

Correctly calculating `x1` to be `2`. Or, you can ask:

```py
s = Solver()
s.add(S(S(Z)) == P(x1, x1))
```

And you get:

```
sat
[x1 = S(Z),
 P = [else ->
      If(Var(0) == Z, Var(1), S(P(pred(Var(0)), Var(1))))]]
```

(You can ignore the assignment to `P`; it's how it is stored in the model.)

While this is how recursive definitions are handled in SMTLib, I should add that such definitions are hard to deal with in the SMTLib formalism. In particular, any theorem that requires induction over `Nat` will be hard to prove, if not impossible, since SMT-solvers don't do induction, at least not yet.

Comment: If it is hard to do even such simple proofs why does Z3 documentation mentions: Algebraic Data Types, forall and exists and call itself Satisfiability modulo theories solver (not just SAT solver)?

Comment: I think the name SMT is quite apt. (See https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2021-05-12.pdf for a more detailed description.) Induction is hard for many tools to do without some human guidance, and SMT solvers usually tend to be "push-button." A typical use case is to use a theorem prover for inductive proofs, and ship the subgoals that don't need induction to the SMT-solver, which can deal with a wide variety of objects such as numbers, bit-vectors, floating-point values etc.

Comment: What did you read to study Z3 and get this knowledge? I read and implemented my code based on this https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html There is no description of RecFunction.

Comment: You found the best document to read on z3 programming, which unfortunately doesn't cover everything. `RecAddDefinition` is documented here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a7029cec3faf5bd7cdd9d9e0365f8a3b5 I do agree that z3 documentation is rather sparse, but if you know where to look you can find the info. Asking at stack-overflow is a great place to start.